# How can I make apache write files as the user it is run as?

Tags: apache, file, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.4, owner

I have an Ubunto 18.04 LTS running with apache2 and various PHP versions (5.6 up to 8.0).
Apache is configured to run as the same user as my FTP user (let's call him 'test').

```
ps aux | grep apache2
```

says this user name for the processes.

Problem: When I run my website on it, which creates a file, then the file is created as user 'www-data', which only works if I give 777 permission to the folder, as the folder has the user 'test' as it's owner.

Question: How can I make apache write files as the user used for the process it runs with?

Output of ps aux | grep apache2:

```
test@webserver:/var/www$ ps aux | grep apache2
root     11101  0.0  0.9 501228 27696 ?        Ss   14:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
test     11103  0.0  0.2 159948  6660 ?        S    14:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
test     11106  0.0  0.5 503824 16896 ?        S    14:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
test     11107  0.0  0.5 503556 15348 ?        S    14:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
test     11109  0.0  0.5 503556 15348 ?        S    14:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
test     11111  0.0  0.5 503556 15348 ?        S    14:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
test     11112  0.0  0.5 503556 15348 ?        S    14:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
test     11114  0.0  0.5 503556 15348 ?        S    14:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
test     11135  0.0  0.0  13144  1024 pts/0    S+   14:45   0:00 grep --color=auto apache2
```

Comment: Can you show the output of that `ps aux | grep apache2` command?

Comment: I put it in the question as it is too long for a comment

Comment: Stickybits might be helpful. [this might be helpful kind of?](https://serverfault.com/a/96349). When I was messing with stickybits, I had a couple problems and asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606319/stickybits-setgid-not-working/606322?noredirect=1#comment1131722_606322). I'm pretty sure my question, plus the comments on the answer has everything you'd need to know. (but idk. It was a lot of searching & hacking together stuff I didn't really know about & that was a few months ago).

Comment: Thanks, but this solves only a small part of the problem. It sets the group, but the user ist still www-data. And www-data is not allowed to write to a 'test' owned directory exept if I have world write access to it.

Comment: Almost 3 months and no solution. Maybe anyone else?